# Inaccurate dipstick reading

Tags: oil

I have owned my car almost 7 years. I've never before checked the oil level with readings like all three of the first holes not having oil in them but the 4th one at the top does. Or at times none of the holes are covered with oil but oil is around the holes on the front and the back of the dipstick. It varies around, even the first and third holes sometimes have oil in them.

I am concerned that someone has put something wrong in my engine to ruin it. Yesterday it was clear and today I drove very little. Now it has a brown color to it and smells burnt. Plus it's overfilled by about a quart.

I have to drive it 100 miles early in the morning then having it changed if it makes it that long...really worried my engine is being ruined. I've always changed the oil when it was due to be. Should I be so concerned? Help/Answers are appreciated.

Comment: are you also checking coolant level? milky brown and level goinig up indicates water in the oil.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the car you are driving?

Comment: Have you changed the oil yourself or do you take it somewhere? If you drain it yourself does it look milky or look to me mixed with another fluid? DO you have reason to believe someone would be sabotaging your car?

Comment: Nate, thanks...Yes someone had added several quarts of some type of oil causing it to be a way overfilled, sabotaging my car. Took it to Snappy lube to get it checked out. Changed the oil and it's fine now except the back main seal and timing chain cover leaks. Just hoping internal parts of the motor wasn't damaged.

Comment: Paulster...2006 Pontiac G6 GT

Comment: agentp..coolant level ok...it was overfilled with oil. Once someone drained my oil thinking I would drive it and ruin it. God gave me a strong feeling to check my oil..thank God..That didn't work so they overfilled it. I lock my doors but that doesn't stop criminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a sample of your oil analyzed for contamination, wear metals and additive package levels.  I work for a Caterpillar distributorship and we have an oil lab in house.  Most heavy equipment dealers offer this service.  A single analysis costs under $20.

Comment: Todd, I regret that I didn't keep any of the oil that Snappy Lube drained from my car. It want start now. Has a new battery and starter in it. It only clicks when I turn the ignition. I'm going to replace the starter fuse tomorrow but I've searched and read that it's possible my engine is locked. Sure hope not though. If it is I'd say the sabotager finally beat me. And I'm broke, can't afford another car nor engine.

Comment: The clicking noise is not likely to be related to contaminated oil.  Most likely an electrical related fault is involved, i.e. battery, starter or power delivery to starter.    What color is the oil in the filler cap where the oil is poured into?  Hopefully it is not milky white.  This would indicate water.

Comment: You got that right Todd. It was my starter in which was new, costed almost $200, I'd bought it 5 months ago. Didn't think it was the starter that was bad but turns out I took it to a shop that rebuilds starters. It had oil packed on the brushing or whatever causing it not to make contact. 3 days after my car was overfilled with oil so I'm wondering if the rear main seal leak is the cause of it or if when the car was overfilled it somehow went to my fly wheel and into the starter. If it's from the rear main seal leak, it will happen again. It's confusing to me. The oil is fine, not milky.